# what's difference between Controller and Handler in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The documentation of Spring MVC sometimes says about "handlers" or "request handlers". For instance, http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.html says:

> Implementation of the HandlerMapping interface to map from URLs to request handler beans

And sometimes it says about controllers. For instance, there is an interface called org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller ( http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html ).

My question is: are Controllers and Handlers the same?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Generally speaking, a Controller is Handler, but a Handler doesn't have to be a Controller.

For example, `HttpRequestHandler`, `WebRequestHandler`, `MessageHandler` are all handlers which can work with the `DispatcherServlet`. ( (`@`)Controller is a handler for executing a web request and returning a view.)

Shortly, Handler is just a term, it is neither a class nor interface. And it is responsible for executing the Mapping.

Answer (score 7):

A [`Controller`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html) is a specific type of `Handler` but not all `Handler`s are `Controller`s.

To execute a type of `Handler` there is a [`HandlerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerAdapter.html) and for each type of `Handler` there is a different `HandlerAdapter`. You have [`Controller`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html) and `@Controller`, [`HttpRequestHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/HttpRequestHandler.html) and also a plain [`Servlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleServletHandlerAdapter.html) can be a `Handler`. Or if you have some custom things you can even implement your own.

Answer (score 2):

*Handler* is a inclusive i.e. covering all the services details.
*Controller* is an an exclusive implementation.

In Spring we have the following different types of handlers:

- `HandlerMapping`: The `HandlerMapping` strategy is used to **map** the HTTP client request to some handler controller(or controllers) and/or method. This is done based on the request URL and the HTTP method, but may also include the request parameters, request headers, or other custom factors.
  **For example:** `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`, `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`.
- `HandlerAdapter`:  The `DispatcherServlet` uses a HandlerAdapter to **invoke** a method. Which is decouples the `DispatcherServlet` from controller implementations classes.
  **For example:** `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, `HttpRequestHandlerAdapter`, `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`, `SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter`, `SimpleServletHandlerAdapter`