# SpringMVC Framework principle

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm a developer from China.I am confused about "handler" and "controller" when I read the working principle of SpringMVC framwork, because "handler" and "controller" are translated into the same thing in Chinese. SO, what are the differences between handler and controller? And could you please tell the working principle of SpringMVC?Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165625/whats-difference-between-controller-and-handler-in-spring-mvc

Comment: @ChiragShah thanks a lot